# JQuery shrink fixed menu animation speed based on scroll speed?

Tags: jquery

I managed to get a fixed menu, that shrinks on scroll, using the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/JJ8Jc/913/

But I would like the animation / shrink speed to follow the scroll speed pixel by pixel, just like you see in the WP Enfold theme: http://www.kriesi.at/themes/enfold/ So when a user only scrolls down 5 pixels from the top, the menu shrinks 5 pixels. And when a user scrolls up 5 pixels, the menu increases 5 pixels in height.

Is that even possible with the animation code I'm currently using? Or does it require a different approach?

Code I'm currently using:

```
$(function(){
    $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
{
    if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big')
    {
        $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
        $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height:'40px'
        },600);
    }
}
else
{
    if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small')
    {
        $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
        $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height:'100px'
        },600);
    }  
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was able to get the exact same fixed menu effect, as seen in the Unfold theme, by modding some jQuery code meant to resize a div through scrolling. And adding a min-height CSS value to the #header_nav class.

Here's the fiddle link showing the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/JJ8Jc/919/

**TIP re menu transparency:** In case you'd like to recreate the transparency of the Unfold menu, simply use a repeat 1px*1px PNG (with a transparency around 90%-95%) as #header_nav background image. Using CSS for this is also possible, but that'll also make your logo and menu items transparent.

In case someone knows of a better solution, I'd still like to hear about it :)

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var $myDiv = $('#header_nav');
        var OriginalHeight = '100';
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        $myDiv.height( OriginalHeight - st );
    }).scroll();
});
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    height:1000px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
}

#header_nav {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    min-height:40px;
    background-color:#666;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#header_nav img {
    height:100%;
}

#content_wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    padding-top:100px;
}
```

Example HTML used:

```
<div id="header_nav"><img src="http://www.kriesi.at/themes/wp-content/plugins/avia_cachable_style_switch/images/logo-enfold/splash-orange.png"/></div>
<div id="content_wrapper">Just some content.</div>
```